# Odd problem. Step through works, runtime doesn't

Tags: debugging, runtime, tabpage

Morning all.

I've seen numerous posts about this problem on here, but nothing specific to my situation so would appreciate some assistance with this.

Essentially, I'm attempting to rearrange the order of tabpages on a tabcontrol, based on the order of entries in a listbox (lbxBuildings).  The number of pages always matches the number of listbox entries, and their text values also match up.

Now I've written the following code which works perfectly when I step through it, but doesn't work (or error) at runtime.

```
    Private Sub cmdBlgSetDown_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdBlgSetDown.Click
    'Make sure our item is not the last one on the list.
    If lbxBuildings.SelectedIndex < lbxBuildings.Items.Count - 1 Then
        'Insert places items above the index you supply, since we want
        'to move it down the list we have to do + 2
        Dim I = lbxBuildings.SelectedIndex + 2
        Dim j As Integer = lbxBuildings.SelectedIndex
        Dim NTP As TabPage = TabControl2.TabPages(j)

        TabControl2.TabPages.Insert(I, NTP)
        TabControl2.SelectedIndex = I - 1
        TabControl2.TabPages.Remove(NTP)

        lbxBuildings.Items.Insert(I, lbxBuildings.SelectedItem)
        lbxBuildings.Items.RemoveAt(lbxBuildings.SelectedIndex)

        lbxBuildings.SelectedIndex = I - 1

    End If
End Sub
```

The rearranging of the listbox is controlled by two buttons (one up and one down) and that all works fine, so I now want the same buttons to rearrange the tabpages as well. There may well be information already entered on these pages prior to their being rearranged, so deleting one and adding a new one won't work for me (as far as I can tell).
My 'solution' of adding in a copy in the correct place then deleting the original makes perfect sense to me and as I say, it works when I step through.  But at runtime, it seems to skip right over the 'insert' line and just deletes the orignal tab.

All suggestions welcome.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well after a load more digging I found mention of this specific problem on a C# site.  More digging still and it turns out that there's a bug in the program with the following workaround.

```
Dim h As IntPtr = TabControl2.Handle
```

Call this 'before' doing anything with the tabcontrol and it works as expected. It's a bit odd but there it is.